# Stop submit operation

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, message

I am trying to stop the submit operation when username field is empty, and display some warning in div with id "err_msg"

```
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
      <form role="form" method="post">
        <div id="data-text">
          <input type="text" name="nick" placeholder="Nick" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Imię" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
          <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Nazwisko" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
          <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telefon" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
          <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Hasło" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
          <input type="text" name="repassword" placeholder="Powtórz hasło" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name='Proceed' value='register' class="btn btn-success">Zarejestruj</button>
      </form>
      <div id="err_msg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that submitting a form refreshes a page, and reset every element to it's default value

Should I handle every field with JS and then use a jQuery to post a data? I don't like possible overkill solutions

Comment: Javascript is the answer here.

Comment: You need javascript and / or `$_POST` values to fill in the default values if they exist. Or `required`, see below.

Comment: You could use javasript and if using html5 you could use require attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
  function validate(){
     noError = TRUE;
     var username = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
     if(username==''){
        noError = FALSE;
     }

     return noError;
  }
</script>

<form role="form" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <div id="data-text">
      <input type="text" name="nick" placeholder="Nick" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Imię" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Nazwisko" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telefon" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Hasło" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="repassword" placeholder="Powtórz hasło" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name='Proceed' value='register' class="btn btn-success">Zarejestruj</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there `html` form attribute `onsubmit` to validation using java-script before form get submitted. Please go through following example to resolve your issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.php"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is to do any stuff you want to do before form submission. But you could use `html5` `require` attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

Example with your code to check for nick:

```
 <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
      <form id="myform" role="form" method="post">
        <div id="data-text">
          <input id="nick" type="text" name="nick" placeholder="Nick" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Imię" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Nazwisko" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telefon" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Hasło" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
      <input type="text" name="repassword" placeholder="Powtórz hasło" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name='Proceed' value='register' class="btn btn-success">Zarejestruj</button>
  </form>
  <div id="err_msg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#myform').on("submit", function() {
    if(!$("#nick").val()) {
         alert("Missing fields");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

However, you should still check for the actually sent values using $_POST (if you use php)